# HTML Custom Elements in firefox/edge

Tags: javascript, html, custom-element

I'm well aware that the **custom elements** feature can be enabled manually by setting `dom.webcomponents.enabled` and `dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled` to true in the configuration (in Firefox at least), but can anyone help me out as to explain why the use of custom elements is encouraged in almost all documentation (w3, mozilla, etc), but only **Chrome** seems to be supported this feature properly.

Lately I've been using this polyfill to get customElements to work on other browser:

```
defineElement = function( tag, opt ){
    if( typeof customElements !== 'undefined' ){
        customElements.define( tag, opt );
    } else {
        document.registerElement( tag, opt );
    }
}
class HTMLxSearchElement extends HTMLElement{
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('super');
    }
}
defineElement( 'x-search', HTMLxSearchElement )
```

But now the `document.registerElement` function has also been removed! Does anyone have any alternatives to get this functionality back up and running?

Comment: "why the use of custom elements is encouraged in almost all documentation" — I'm not been given that impression at all.

Comment: In which browser(s) and which version that you're testing on, has `document.registerElement` been removed?

Comment: @DhruvMurarka currently testing in the latest Firefox Quantum v59.0.1 and Edge 41.16299.248.0. They both seem to be lacking the function.

Comment: @Supersharp You're absolutely right. I only just noticed that their information was missing totally from any of the documentation regarding `registerElement`.

It still does not explain why Firefox has removed the `registerElement` feature and set `customElements` as the new standard, while it has to be manually turned on.

Answer (score 4):

For now just use the polyfill https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element . It's align to the Custom Element v1. It's working fine with IE10+ and all other browsers.
For more and newest information see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/

Answer (score 1):

I was running into customElements not defined error on the Edge browser with my web component that I created using Angular Elements and my solution was to run:

`npm i -S document-register-element`

and in my Angular Elements projects polyfills.ts file, I added:

`import 'document-register-element'`

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use of Custom Elements v1 is *encouraged* in some documentations because it is a [HTML/Javascript WHATWG standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#custom-elements).

Now it's [implemented](https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1) in Chrome, but also is Opera and Safari.

`registerElement` doesn't work any more with Firefox 59+  because Custom Element v0 implementation [was deprecated](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1396765).

Comment: So  what is a healthy replacement for it? customElements need to be enabled by the user in FF, I can't imagine that being a normal situation

Comment: @BRO_THOM you can use a polyfill until it is activated by default

Comment: Considering the use of it is encouraged, but it's not enabled by default and it's not standardised for other browsers, it seems like a poor decision to use a method which isn't standard at all.

Comment: Actually it is standardized

Comment: you can't call a method standard, if it's not enabled by default.

Comment: It's not you who decides what is standard but a standardization comitee (WHATWG or W3C). Moreover browsers that implement Custom Elements natively represent 80% of the desktop market, and even more of the mobile market.

Comment: Did you not read my previous comment? How can you standardise a feature if it requires a user to enable it. The fact that its not enabled by default is a fault by design imho

Comment: Yes I read it, hence my answer. It seems that you misuse the word "standard". The fact that in firefox a new feature is launched under a flag is not a fault, is very common, and relies on very good and evident reasons

Comment: @BRO_THOM It is a standard that is being worked on in all browsers. But not everyone is finished at the same time, thus the existence of a polyfill until all of the browsers support it. That is how most browser standards go. The group agrees on the standard, they create a polyfill, when possible, and then each company starts working on it. When a browser supports the new standard the polyfill does nothing on that browser. Once all browsers, that your team cares about, support it then you can stop using the polyfill.

Answer (score -1):

Native Custom Elements V1 spec implementation is available in FireFox as of version 63.

So `Chrome`, `FireFox`, `Opera` and parallel mobile version for those are all supporting custom elements.

`Safari`'s support lacks customized built-in elements up till now.